# Trying to Drag-n-Drop more than 9 files into batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, command-line-arguments

The code below is a simple example of what I'm trying to do. Basically, I want to be able to drag and drop more than 9 files into this script and have it iterate through each file one by one instead and run them through the "Run_Conversion_1064.bat" script.

The SHIFT method doesn't seem to be applicable to what I'm trying to accomplish.

```
ECHO Running BATCH....
cd /d %~dp0

CALL Run_Conversion_1064.bat %1 
CALL Run_Conversion_1064.bat %2 
CALL Run_Conversion_1064.bat %3
CALL Run_Conversion_1064.bat %4 
CALL Run_Conversion_1064.bat %5 
CALL Run_Conversion_1064.bat %6
CALL Run_Conversion_1064.bat %7
CALL Run_Conversion_1064.bat %8
CALL Run_Conversion_1064.bat %9

pause

goto end
```

Comment: I'd be interested in seeing what you'd tried with the SHIFT method, because that's where I'd start.  Can you post how you tried that too?

Comment: Try this single line batch file first: `@(For %%G In (%*) Do @Call "%~dp0Run_Conversion_1064.bat" %%G) & Pause`, or perhaps `@PushD "%~dp0" 2>NUL && (For %%G In (%*) Do @Call "Run_Conversion_1064.bat" %%G) & Pause`.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
@echo off

:again


call "C:\temp\20211117\Run_Conversion_1064.bat" %1
shift

if "%1"=="" goto :done
goto :again


:done
pause
```

Note I've used the full path to `Run_Conversion_1064.bat` because it's not on my path.

`Run_Conversion_1064.bat` gets the full path to each file, e.g. `"C:\temp\poc2449.patch"`

Did what I expected dropping 14 files onto this batch file.

Comment: no need for the `:Done` Label. Use instead: `If not "%~1"=="" Goto:Again`

Comment: What if there is no argument at all?

Answer (score 0):

Using `shift` or `%*` are the only ways to deal with > 9 arguments as far as I know.

```
@echo off
if "%~1"=="" goto help

:loop
echo Do something with %~1
shift
if not "%~1"=="" goto loop
goto :EOF

:help
echo.Run me with some parameters...

rem For this example, provide dummy arguments and run self
call %0 foo "hello world" 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 bar
```